# Reloading the TableView Section on NSTimer

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nstimer

I am reloading the particular tableview's section on NSTimer which i scheduled on the 0.05 seconds. I have a button in that section cell But once timer starts, I am not able to get button click event.

Kindly help me:)
Thanks In Advance

Comment: your sample codes attach please.

Comment: If cell count is not changed, you can just update visible cells. it will be faster.

Comment: How often does the tableview content actually change? Wouldn't reloading just when the content changes be better?

Comment: @NeverBe Yes, In my case, Cell count is not changing & I have a single cell in each section So thats I preferred to reload the section.

Comment: can you post your code...??
it's working in my case

Comment: and why are you reloading your table on nstimer...if u want to reload the table reload it when ever the data source is updated...

Comment: @sosborn Actually I am trying to display the different Countdown in each cell which will be controlled by respective Play & Pause button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot press the button is because you are constantly reloading the tableView, so the button gets reinitialized while you are pressing it.

There are two solutions (one is better for you, but without seeing your code I cannot tell which).

Solution A: Instead of calling reloadData on the tableview, only update the labels in the cells.

Solution B: Reuse your UITableViewCells and only initialize the button when needed, not on every reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back and think about what you're trying to do here:

You have a UITableView with one cell in it that should be updated at 20 Hz.

Twenty. Hertz.

What happens when you `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`

1. The TableView asks its data source for the number of rows in that section.
2. The TableView must ask its delegate whether it implements `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` — if it does, it needs to call that method.
3. The TableView asks its data source for a cell, which will then try to dequeue one (that's if there was a reuse identifier...) and configure that cell.
4. The TableView will then take this cell and insert it in the view hierarchy, remove the old one and will then call layout its subviews.

Twenty. Whopping. Times. A. Second.

Don't do that!

Instead, only perform changes if you really have to. Otherwise you drain the battery for nothing and your UI will be sluggish as hell because all that load you just caused blocks the event loop.